# How can I verify and create values on the Windows registry with Python?

Tags: python, registry

How is the simpler way to verify if the value is already created or create Windows registry values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the standard Python library module [_winreg](http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html) (it's renamed to `winreg`, no leading `_`, if you're using Python 3).

You always start with one of the constant keys named `_winreg.HKEY`something; to see them all, do:

```
 >>> import _winreg
 >>> [k for k in dir(_winreg) if k.startswith('HKEY')]
```

and repeatedly use (to navigate down the keys' tree) functions such as [_winreg.Openkey](http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html#_winreg.OpenKey) (in a `try`/`except` to catch the `WindowsError` it raises when a key is not present).

Comment: So it's `_winreg`, as I said first (most people are on Python 2.something, and `_winreg` is how the module is named from Python 2.0 to 2.7).

Answer (score 1):

you can use _winreg. here's an example enumerating the startup(Run)

```
import _winreg
j=0
startup = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run")
while 1:
    try:
        print  _winreg.EnumValue(startup,j)
        j+=1
    except : break
```